# Populate environment in non-interactive session

Tags: linux, environment-variables, embedded, sysvinit

I'm working on an embedded device that runs Yocto Poky as distro.

The final product will have several applications that are started by `SysVinit`. There is only one `root` user.

I have some scripts, both in `/etc/init.d` and `/etc/profile.d` that add some environment variables needed by our applications. The problem I'm facing is that, if I run the app "by hand" (so I have an interactive shell) they run nicely, since the scripts in `/etc/profile.d/` were sourced, but when ran by `SysVinit`, they cannot find the environment populated (obviously). We are using `sh` as shell.

I read about different files like `.bashrc`, `.profile` and some variables like `ENV` and `BASH_ENV`. I tried to define my variables there, but without luck. A small workaround I found is launching my main application in a login shell (from `SysVinit`):

```
2:12345:once:/bin/sh -lc /usr/bin/my_app
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I set the environment during boot (aka without logging in) or let `SysVinit` do it in a nice way?
2. The exports performed in `/etc/init.d` scripts do not propagate to my environment at all; that's because those scripts are run in a subshell, and not sourced in the current one (that will required login two) I guess, so how can I export variables from there?
3. Is my workaround a valid solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How can I set the environment during boot (aka without logging in) or let SysVinit doing it, in a nice way?

During the boot environment is clean (isn't initialised jet). You need put env variables via `source` or `.` commands for `sh` (if your service is a script) or initialise it in the program (i.e. via config file).

Small example of service script header:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -f /etc/profile.d/needed.sh ] && . /etc/profile.d/needed.sh

. . .
```

> 2. The exports performed in /etc/init.d scripts do not propagate to my environment at all, that's because those script are run in a subshell,
>      and not sourced in the current one (that will required login two) I
>      guess, so how can I export variables from there?

`source` your env variables for subshells or call commands with specified env variable.

Small example of service script header:

```
#!/bin/bash

. . .

$(BASH_ENV=/etc/profile.d/needed.sh command)
$(ENV_VAR1=value1 command)

. . .
```

> 3. Is my workaround a valid solution?

If it's work - it's dirty way for the service. See 1. and 2.